# Getting html code of facebook specific page

Tags: java, html, facebook, jsoup, web-crawler

I am trying to get html code of specific page in facebook but the problem is that my code gives me the html of no-user in facebook.

```
String html = Jsoup.connect("https://www.facebook.com/mor.amit.3/about").get().html();
System.out.println(html);
```

For example when i try to do it, it gives me her page but from side of no-facebook user.
how can i use this code and look on her profile from user side?

Comment: anyway what kind of information about user do you want to get ?

Comment: education, birthday etc 
With the facebook api its impossible with user access token, only with app ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't get birthday ,education  or some specific information without login to facebook because of privacy  settings of Facebook user.for example if you logout from fb and view that profile .you will get this .so there is no information about birthday .you have to log to fb using java then you will be able to download expected page

[image]

Comment: Yes it works when I logged to Facebook through java
thank you

Comment: *I will just note that it can be done easily with using cookie of logged in user instead of create all the process of log into Facebook.

Comment: @user3100708 yes you can